# doOnNext() never called

Tags: android, rx-android

Given the following chain:

```
 public Observable<List<PoiCollection>> findPoiCollectionsByUserId(Integer userId) {
    return findUserGroupsByUserId(userId)
            .flatMapIterable(
                    userGroups -> userGroups)
            .flatMap(
                    userGroup -> findPoiCollectionToUserGroupsByUserGroupId(userGroup.getId()))
            .flatMapIterable
                    (poiCollectionToUserGroups -> poiCollectionToUserGroups)
            .flatMap(
                    poiCollectionToUserGroup -> {
                        Observable<PoiCollection> poiCollectionById = findPoiCollectionById(poiCollectionToUserGroup.getPoiCollectionId());
                        return poiCollectionById;
                    })
            .toList()
            .doOnNext(poiCollections -> {
                Timber.d("poi-collections from DB:", poiCollections);
                for(PoiCollection collection : poiCollections) {
                    Timber.d("collection:", collection);
                }
            })
            .doOnError(throwable ->
                    Timber.e("error fetching poi-collections for user from DB"));
}
```

Which is invoked like this:

```
Observable<List<PoiCollection>> fromDB = databaseHelper.findPoiCollectionsByUserId(id);

fromDB.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
                poiCollections -> {
                    Activity activity = (Activity) getView();
                          Intent intent = new Intent(activity, PoiCollectionsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("poi_collections", (Serializable) poiCollections);
                    activity.startActivity(intent);
                    activity.finish();
                },
                throwable -> {
                    if (throwable instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
                        getView().showInternetDialog();
                    }
                });
```

I find myself wondering why neither `doOnNext(...)` nor `doOnError(...)` is being invoked. The chain is being executed until `toList()`, thus the below lines are being executed, it just stops afterwards.

```
poiCollectionToUserGroup -> {
            Observable<PoiCollection> poiCollectionById = findPoiCollectionById(poiCollectionToUserGroup.getPoiCollectionId());
            return poiCollectionById;
        })
```

A breakpoint at `poiCollectionById` and another one inside `findPoiCollectionById(...)` clearly show, the result is being fetched from DB successfully!

So, what's preventing `doOnNext(...)` from being called? I clearly invoke `subscribe(...)` on the observable. The mapping chain runs until `toList()`. I never see the code run into `doOnError(...)`, nor do I ever run into the `Action<Throwable>` part of `subscribe(...)`. Must have something to do with `toList()`.

Comment: Are u getting items emitted in onNext() when subscribed?

Comment: can you put doOnNext() before toList() and try.

Comment: Yes, I can, I expected so aswell. The issue is the toList() invokation. However, I must be able to create a List. Pointless otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to my question, but a solution to my problem

```
public Observable<List<PoiCollection>> findPoiCollectionsByUserId(Integer userId) {

    List<PoiCollection> poiCollections = new ArrayList<>();

    findUserGroupsByUserId(userId)
            .flatMap(Observable::from)
            .flatMap(userGroup -> findPoiCollectionToUserGroupsByUserGroupId(userGroup.getId()))
            .flatMap(Observable::from)
            .flatMap(poiCollectionToUserGroup -> findPoiCollectionById(poiCollectionToUserGroup.getPoiCollectionId()))
            .doOnNext(collection -> poiCollections.add(collection))
            .subscribe();

    return Observable.just(poiCollections);
}
```

I really wish I hadn't had to create the `ArrayList`, but rather do something like the `collect(Collectors.toList())` method of Java 8 Stream API by utilizing rxJavas `toList()`.